# smart contract Thether balanceOf method returns 0x

Tags: tokens, ether, json-rpc, myetherwallet, web3j

i used web3j-java call Tether contract method balanceOf(the server node is mine , and on ether mainnet),my address has 3USDT,but i call balanceOf , the node returns me 0x as the balance value,it is not correct ,and how to resolve this problem. the geth version is 1.9.24 . block-chain had been sync finished.

my eth node start firewall,is someone help me to solve this problem,please contact me. and provide you more info about this.

Contract Address is: 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7

My Address is: 0xf19c930fad206da25f89a6b740fb1fdb403b351c

geth process: /root/eth/geth --http --allow-insecure-unlock --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.api admin,debug,web3,eth,txpool,personal,ethash,miner,net --http.corsdomain "*" --http.vhosts "*"

goals: get address USDT balance under Thether Token

codes:

```
    Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("http://27.102.106.58:8545"));
    List<Type> inputParameters = new ArrayList<>();
    Address address = new Address("0xf19c930fad206da25f89a6b740fb1fdb403b351c");
    inputParameters.add(address);
    List<TypeReference<?>> outputParameters = new ArrayList<>();
    TypeReference<Uint256> typeReference = new TypeReference<Uint256>(){};
    outputParameters.add(typeReference);
    Function function = new Function("balanceOf", inputParameters, outputParameters);
    String encodeFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
    org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.request.Transaction transaction = org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.request.Transaction
            .createEthCallTransaction("0xf19c930fad206da25f89a6b740fb1fdb403b351c", "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7", encodeFunction);
    EthCall ethCall;
    BigInteger balanceValue = BigInteger.ZERO;
    try {
        ethCall = web3j.ethCall(transaction, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).send();
        List<Type> results = FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(ethCall.getValue(), function.getOutputParameters());
        balanceValue = (BigInteger) results.get(0).getValue();//here is 0x
        System.out.println(balanceValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is the address of the contract? What is the address of your account? What is your code for doing so? And finally - what makes you think that anyone can answer your question without these very basic details???

Comment: thanks pretty , and provide more info about this question.